# Accidentally deleted IOS on 3750G Switch

Tags: terminal, server, ip, putty, cisco

I accidentally deleted the IOS on 3750G Switch. As a result, I am thrown in the ROMMON mode when I console into the switch via Putty. I tried the following:

1) I set up my static IP as 192.168.168.167 255.255.255.0 with default gateway as the same as my switch's IP 192.168.168.168

2) I set the IP on the switch as 192.168.168.168 255.255.255.0 and default gateway as 192.168.168.167. I set the TFTP Server's IP same as my laptop's static IP.

3) Then I typed tftpdnld after I placed the new IOS on the to TFTP root folder. 
That failed when I did all this on Putty. The switch was not able to read the Ethernet cable.

**By the way, the show command does not work on ROMMON mode via Putty**

Furthermore, the show command does not work on ROMMON mode. I have the IOS that will be uploaded into the switch. But how do I do that? Please help. Thanks. I am doing all this via console. Here is the site I used as a guide: http://www.mikcx.com/cisco-ios-deleted-by-mistake-recovery-guide/

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. Delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed and followed the rules below (I used ExtraPutty!!)

There are times when the IOS on a switch may crash and (as a last resort) you need to use the painfully slow Xmodem transfer to save your life. I bought a 3550 a while back and that is precisely what happened with me. Without much else to try, I decided to give Xmodem a shot. I want to share how this can be used and I hope that this may be useful to others.

Since the device is in ROMMON, there’s not much that you can do.  There is, however, a method to transfer another IOS using a direct  console connection with a PC (the transfer is over your console cable itself). This wonderful little thing is called  Xmodem. Now the rate of transfer depends on the baud rate that you set  for your console connection. I tried this with baud set to 9600 and man,  it seemed like it would take over 3 hours for the transfer to complete.  With a little trial and error, I found that the maximum baud rate I  could set it up to work perfectly with was 57600. You can set the baud  rate in ROMMON using the set BAUD  command. See below:

switch: set BAUD 57600

This MUST also match on the terminal program setting as well. So (I’m  using TeraTerm) under Setup -> Serial Port, set the baud rate to  match whatever you set it as in ROMMON. Now we’re ready to transfer the  file. The command is very straight forward:

switch: copy xmodem: flash:c3550-ipservicesk9-mz.122-44.SE6.bin

Once you press enter, you see the following:

Begin the Xmodem or Xmodem-1K transfer now…
C

At this point, you need to choose the file location from the terminal  program. Go under File -> Transfer -> Xmodem -> Send and  choose the file that you wish the transfer. The transfer will start and  you will see a transfer window pop up. I made sure when the following image popped on ExtraPutty terminal --->  flash:c3750-ipbasek9-mz.150-2.SE8.bin Begin the Xmodem or Xmodem-1K transfer now... CCCCCCCCCCxmodem and I quickly went to the panel and click Xmodem located at the panel on top and click send and drag the c3750-ipbasek9-mz.150-2.SE8.bin file and have it sent through. Hence it explained why I kept get an  I/O error, which made sense. Input error because the switch was waiting for me to send it the OS file.

Please take a look at this link for future reference and many thanks to this author who wrote this up: https://supportforums.cisco.com/blog/151336/loading-ios-switch-xmodem